# Enabling intelliJ Hibernate HQL code assistance on a String

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, hql

IntelliJ currently provides code completion / checking for HQL queries that are used directly in creating queries.

Is there any way to enable this checking on Strings? The strings are then passed down to objects that create the query, so it would be beneficial if we could have them checked at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the answer - in Settings / Language Injections, you can add a new "Java Paramter" / "Hibernate QL" setting and specify the class that you wish to enable the content assist for.